# foundation 3.1 tooltips are not displaying

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I am trying to get the foundation 3 tooltips to display but when I mouse over the span element it displays the standard tool tip.

[image]

I am referencing the following js files

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>   
<script src="/js/modernizr.foundation.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.foundation.forms.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Element:

```
<span class="has-tip tip-top noradius" data-width="210" title="Bottom and the default position.">Your Target Price</span>
```

Do I need to initialize the code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to reference the all important style sheets(foundation.min.css), add this to the top of your page where you reference you javascripts:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/foundation.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/app.css"/>
```

Also you should update to Zurb-Foundation 3.2

Comment: I had the css files referenced already. It was updating to Zurb-Foundation 3.2 that did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

The scripts are being referenced in the wrong order. `app.js` should **always** appear last since it initializes the plugins.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>   
<script src="/js/jquery.foundation.forms.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also `modernizr.js` should be in the `<head>`.http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing

```
<script src="/js/modernizr.foundation.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```